# How to create a resizable and movable TitleWindow in D3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, crossfilter

I want to create a component similar to the Panel/TitleWindow in Flex, but with D3. It should be resizable and movable.

I want to include inside it a bar chart in which I have the names of the bars on the left and the bars on the right. But, I want to be able to change the width of the labels by dragging a control at the top (header area). When resizing the Panel the bar will scale (width) accordingly and a vertical scroller will appear (if needed) if the height of all the bars is larger than the height of the container (the Panel).

I have create a Resizable and Movable Panel in D3 using SVG, but I am afraid once I include the bar chart inside I will not be able to include scrollbars (vertical) if needed. Hence, I am looking for ideas of how to solve the problem. One possibility is to make the panle with divs. I am not good with CSS, so I have no idea how to create it with divs.

satckoverflow doesn't allow me to put another link in the post, so I am not including the link to jsfiddle with the current implementation with SVGs.

I need this, because I am creating a D3 & Crossfilter app where each dimension will be hosted on a panel. And since the number of categories per dimension can change and even the # of panels could be defined by the data itself, I need to be able to move and resize the panels.

I draft implementation of the idea can bee seen at http://mylinerider.com/D3/ImportExport.html. To filter the data you need to click on a bar, It acn filter multiple categories by dimension and change measures. However, the panels cannot be move or scaled.

I have created an example in Flex of what I want to do with D3/JS for the panel -  http://mylinerider.com/panel/

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of reinventing things -- if you have an implementation that works for you already, why reimplement it? What are the advantages you hope to have by doing it in D3?

Comment: I am building a new visualization in D3 that needs that functionality. My current solution is in Flex which requires the Flash Player. So i need to build the same kind of component in JS.

The solution that I have in D3 is based on SVGs, but I need to include inside other elements that may need a scrollbar. Using DIVs will allow to do that better, but I don't know enough CSS to create them exactly how I need them and my code for the resize and move events would be different. Hre is the jsfiddle for the one in SVG.

Comment: Have you seen jQuery UI? In particular the [Dialog component](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: Lars, that seems promising. I will look into it. Thanks.